# loading jQuery at the end of the page for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been told loading jQuery at the end of a page increases performance for mobile.

I don't believe this, however open for an explanation.

Regardless, is there any way to get jQuery calls at the beginning of the page to load only after jQuery has been loaded? I know of timeout work around but they seem inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get "better" performance is that the page will be parsed before it reaches JavaScript at the end of the document, and once a section is parsed, rendering can begin. By loading JavaScript at the end of the document, you let the basic hard-coded layout in your HTML and CSS appear before you add functionality with JavaScript. This gives the user the illusion of "faster loading time" for your page.

The caveat here is any JavaScript you want to use that will call on external libraries must occur after the libraries' script tags. This is not an issue if you have packed all of your code together into its own file, but it will cause trouble for inline scripts you have strewn about the page.

This is part of why such behavior is discouraged in production applications, the rest having to do with the ability to maximize compression of the script content with gzip and so on.